# Mongo extract hostname field db.hostinfo

Tags: mongodb

I'm new to Mongo.

I can run db.hostInfo(), and it outputs lots of information, but I just want to see the "system"."hostname" field.

How do i do that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
db.hostInfo().system.hostname
```

Answer (score 1):

Type and hit **enter** =>

```
db.hostInfo().system.hostname
```

[image]

*This command works on Linux(Ubuntu20.04) and Win10.*